# Redirecting domain to specific page but not the pages from that domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm in the process of moving my multi-site Wordpress website with domain mapping to a single installation.
For this I want the old mapped domains (domainA.com, domainB.com, etc.) referred to specific pages on the new domain (so, newdomain.com/domainA, newdomain.com/domainB, etc.) BUT I also want the original pages of the old domains to go to pages on the new website (domainA.com/page should become newdomain.com/page) and I want it to show the new url, not the old url in the bar. This is the part I'm struggling with.
I could do this all manually in htaccess, I suspect, but one of the websites would then require 80+ pages rewritten that way in the htaccess and I don't think that's the best plan.

Currently, newdomain and domainA are both on the same hosting and domainA is an alias of newdomain. In this setup, I manage to refer domainA.com to newdomain.com/domainA, and show that correctly as the url, but if I go to domainA.com/page then it will send the visitor to the correct page on the website (newdomain.com/page) but it doesn't show the correct url, it will still show the original url (domainA.com/page).
If I turn the alias into a domain pointer, it refers domainA.com to the main page of newdomain.com, not the specific page I want it to go, but then it does show the correct url when going to the specific page, which is normal domain pointer behaviour. But it doesn't solve the issue.

This is the current code I'm using:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:/www.newdomain.com/domainA/$1 [R=301,L]
# END WordPress
```

I want people who go to domainA.com to be sent to newdomain.com/domainA/ while people who go to domainA.com/page are sent to newdomain.com/page with the newdomain url showing in the bar. As it stands, I seem to only be able to do one of the two, depending on if domainA is set to alias or to domain pointer.

As per Misorude's first comment below, I changed the code, the rest is the exact same as above, it's also still in the same location:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /domainA/ [R=301,L]
```

The output for this is now domainA.com/domainA/, while it shows the page of newdomain.com/domainA, but the url in the bar shows the old domain.
Using the full url in the rewrite simply adds the total url behind the domainA url and of course gives an error since it doesn't exist.

Full current code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/domainA/ [R=301,L]
# END WordPress
```

This sends the visitor from domainA.com to domainA.com/http:/www.newdomain.com/domainA/.

Comment: You only want to redirect to `newdomain.com/domainX/`, if the requested URL path was just `/`. Since in .htaccess context the leading slash has already been stripped from that, you want to target an _empty_ path: `RewriteRule ^$ …` Appending $1 makes little sense, because you want anything that was not a request for just `/` to be handled differently.

Comment: You want to redirect `domainA.com/page` to `newdomain.com/page` - the same for `domainB.com/page` then? Then use a RewriteCond that checks if the host name of the request was _not_ `newdomain.com` already, and follow with a RewriteRule that matches everything `(.*)`, and rewrites to `newdomain.com/$1`

Comment: @misorude As per your first comment, using that now turns the url into either `domainA.com/newdomain.com/domainA` or into `domainA.com/domainA`, but not `newdomain.com/domainA` in the url (it goes to the page, but doesn't show the right url).

Comment: Can you show the exact code you tried? (Please edit it into the question, in comments extended code is hard to read.)

Comment: @misorude I've added the new code and the new results to the question.

Comment: `/domainA/` is a relative path only, how is the server supposed to know that you meant this to be underneath the new domain? You of course need to still provide the  full URL here, `http:/www.newdomain.com/domainA/`

Comment: @misorude If I do that, then the url changes to `domainA.com/http://www.newdomain.com/domainA`.

Comment: _“If I do that”_ - _what exactly_? Again, show the full rule you tried.

Comment: (You should do your own rewrites that try and change the domain _before_ any of that wordpress routing, if that’s not the case already.)

Comment: @misorude `RewriteRule ^$ http:/www.newdomain.com/domainA/ [R=301,L]` gets the result I mention above, where the full url is added to the old url.

Comment: Then it must be some side effect of the other rules that exist. Show the full current .htaccess contents, in proper order.

Comment: @misorude I've pasted the current content of htaccess in the question. There is no other code in there than this.

Comment: You need to do the domain rewriting stuff before the WordPress rewrites.

Comment: Seems I can read over the same coding error 100 times and not catch it, missing / after http. Now it sends to the correct base url to the correct page, but domainA.com/page still shows the original url in the bar even when it shows the correct new page.

Comment: Well you haven’t added a redirect for `domainA.com/page` yet … see my second comment.

Comment: @misorude Yep, added that one, and after a couple of blips, it finally worked. Pulling it out of both the wordpress and the IfModule block made everything work as it was supposed to. Thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
#send only the base url of domainA to specific link
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/domainA/ [R=301,L]
#Send all non-newdomain links to the specific page on the newdomain website
#while showing newdomain as the proper website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This allows for easy addition of extra domains to be rerouted without doing extra work.